# What causes and how to fix lifting floorboard?

Tags: floor, subfloor

It doesn't seem to want to lift up. I assume it is some sort of tongue and groove board because there are no nails or screws anywhere. When I press down on the lifted part with a lot of force it barely moves down. Not sure what to do here.
[image]

Comment: Take piece of scrap 2x4 and place it on top of the offending board, Take a heavy hammer and wack the 2x4 like you mean it. Report back. **Alaska man is not responsible if you hit your thumb or split any of the boards**.

Comment: the boards looks to be too long, shorten it. a dremel or oscillating saw would be the easiest way to do that w/o removal. could maybe even use a chisel or pocketknife or emery board and elbow grease...

Comment: @dandavis What makes you say that? When I stand directly over it there is a small gap between the two boards indicating it is not too long. This would also mean the lift would disappear in the winter but it does not.

Comment: from the pic, it (really really) _looks_ to me like the high board is on top of the one closest to the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Wood moves over time, no real way around that. The board could have been fitted so tightly originally, that over time it expanded just enough to force it up.

As already suggested, you could trying smacking it down with a piece of scrap wood and hammer.  If that works, there are special screws you can use to screw the board down more permanently. The screw head is designed to break off to make as little of an appearance in the board as possible.

Comment: Well I smacked the absolute **** out of it and while it sticks up slightly less the issue persists. Can you link me to such screws? Or the name of them? I just screw them in near the problem area and hope it holds it down?

Comment: break away screws https://www.homedepot.com/p/Squeeeeek-No-More-Hardwood-Squeak-Elimination-Kit-3232/100662994